# Código com Repetição vba

Tags: vba

O código abaixo não executa nas linhas seguintes:

```
Sub concatena()
 
linha = 13

Do While Cells(linha, 2) <> ""


Dim Data As String
    Data = Cells(linha + 1, 2)

  Range("q13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Format(Data, "mmmm" & "yyyy")
  Range("r13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Range("q13") & Range("k13")
  Range("v13").Select
    Selection = Range("i13") & Range("n13") & Range("j13")

With Selection

Dim x As String
    x = Cells(linha, 2)

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4") Then
  Range("s13") = Sheets("FLC").Range("E9")
Else
  Range("s13") = Sheets("FLC").Range("F9")
End If

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4") Then
  Range("t13") = Range("i13") & Sheets("FLC").Range("E9")
Else
  Range("s13") = Range("i13") & Sheets("FLC").Range("F9")
End If

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4") Then
  Range("u13") = Sheets("Tabelas").Range("w2") & Range("j13") & Range("i13")
Else
  Range("u13") = Sheets("Tabelas").Range("w3") & Range("j13") & Range("i13")
End If

End With

  linha = linha + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Dá qual erro, e onde?

Comment: Além disso, eu tenho a impressão de que o código poderia estar melhor arquitetado. Se puder explicar melhor qual sua intenção e qual o contexto, seria mais fácil de dar uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegue compartilhar o erro com a gente? Talvez assim possamos ser mais assertivos numa solução. Porém vi que falta uma instrução no seu código. Consegue testar desta maneira? Apenas adicionar o ".value" já resolva.

```
Sub concatena()
 
linha = 13

Do While Cells(linha, 2).value <> ""


Dim Data As String
    Data = Cells(linha + 1, 2).value

  Range("q13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Format(Data, "mmmm" & "yyyy")
  Range("r13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Range("q13") & Range("k13")
  Range("v13").Select
    Selection = Range("i13").value & Range("n13").value & Range("j13").value

With Selection

Dim x As String
    x = Cells(linha, 2)

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4").value Then
  Range("s13").value = Sheets("FLC").Range("E9").value
Else
  Range("s13").value = Sheets("FLC").Range("F9").value
End If

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4").value Then
  Range("t13").value = Range("i13").value & Sheets("FLC").Range("E9").value
Else
  Range("s13").value = Range("i13").value & Sheets("FLC").Range("F9").value
End If

If x < Sheets("FLC").Range("m4").value Then
  Range("u13").value = Sheets("Tabelas").Range("w2").value & Range("j13") & Range("i13").value
Else
  Range("u13").value = Sheets("Tabelas").Range("w3").value & Range("j13") & Range("i13").value
End If

End With

  linha = linha + 1
Loop

End Sub
```